# If $\exists {a}^{-1}$ such that ${a} * {a}^{-1} (\mod {m}) = 1$, prove ${a}, {a}^{2}, ... (\mod {m})$ is a repeating sequence.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Solution:
[image]

The maximum cardinality of $ S = \{{a}^{k} \mod{m}\} $ is clearly $m$, how can we know that ${a}^{k} \mod{m}$ will produce values in a predictable order?

Comment: The solution doesn't really care that the $a^k$ form a *predictable* sequence, although this is a consequence of the fact that it has repetition. Indeed, if $a^k=a^j$, then $a^{k+n}=a^{j+n}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, so after the first repetition it will definitely be cyclical.

Comment: Just to be clear about the problem you posted itself, if the sequence did not have repetitions $\text{mod $m$}$, this would mean there are infinitely many *distinct* $\text{mod $m$}$ values. This is absurd, so the sequence must have repetitions.

Comment: And adding on that, if it repeats once it will have attained a previous value and continue to repeat because of that

Comment: Why doesn't the solution care that ${a}^{k}$ forms a predictable sequence? I thought that there can be repetitions iff a predictable sequence is formed.

For instance, if ${a}^{k} \mod{m}$ produced the sequence {1, 3, 2}, how can we be sure that it will never produce {1, 3, 3}?

There are also cases where the repetition begins before $m$ terms have passed (example: ${2}^{k} \mod{7}$, which produces the sequence {1, 2, 4})

Comment: The sequence is predictable becuase modular reduction preserves structure. The correct term is that it is a homomorphism. So in your example, if you see $\{1,3,2\}$ you can never see $\{1,3,3\}$ because $3a=2$ mod $m$ regardless of how the $3$ was derived as the residue of $a^k$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle#Uses_and_applications

Answer (score 0):

The [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) is at work here. If we have $n > k$ items that can take at most $k$ values, then at least two elements take the same value. As the sequence has infinite elements that can take $m$ possible values, then it repeats somewhere.

Then $a^m = a^n$ for some $m > n$. It follows that $a^{n}a^{m-n} = a^n$. We can cancel $a^n$ (multiplying  $n$ times by $a^{-1}$) and we have $a^{m-n} = 1$.

If $m-n = 1$ then $a = 1$, so $a^{-1} = a$, which is in $S$.

If $m-n > 1$ then we have $a^{m-n-1}\cdot a = a \cdot a^{m-n-1} = 1$, but then $a^{-1} = a^{m-n-1}$ which is a member of $S$.

Therefore $a^{-1} \in S$. Then the sequence will repeat after reaching $a^{-1}$:

$a, a^2, a^3, \cdots , a^{-1}, 1, a, a^2, \cdots $.